# Alternate ISO image for current unstable (alpha/beta) releases

Tags: 64-bit, iso, release-management, ubuntu-minimal

I'm looking for minimal/alternate ISO image files of current unstable releases. Where can I find them?

Furthermore, are the core packages in the command line installs stable enough for daily use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Milestone builds (Alphas and such) are always linked from:

- http://www.ubuntu.com/testing

Daily builds of ISOs are available here:

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/

How usable they are isn't really answerable, it really depends on what's going in the archive that day, see this question for more info:

- [When are questions about "ubuntu+1" appropriate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)

Comment: Thank you! I got what I was looking for -  and if it's not too much of a bother, can you link me to the Natty Alpha 2's Unity meta-package as well? Googling never helps when looking for them.

Comment: it's just "unity"

Answer (score 0):

You can find them usually in the same place where you find unstable live cds, however the packages are just as unstable and you should avoid them for daily use.